# Simple Storage Space - more disks = faster read by slower write?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, storage-spaces

I'm trying to make use of some older, smaller disks & get maximum performance from them to hold Steam games/temporary photo editing files etc. - no resilience required.

(Disclaimer, I have 4 disks, one is attached by SATA, the other 3 are currently in external docks attached by USB 3).

As I'm trying to find the settings for maximum performance I pooled the 4 disks and created 4 virtual disks with differing numbers of columns/interleave size.

D: = 1 column, 128KB interleave

E: = 2 columns, 64KB interleave

F: = 3 columns, 64KB interleave (didn't expect much from this setup but did it anyway because: experimenting)

H: = 4 columns, 32KB interleave

All formatted NTFS, 128KB allocation unit size. (I'm attempting to match the AUS to the stripe size).

The image below shows the performance of each.

What I can't understand is why the write performance gets so drastically poor whilst the read performance drastically improves as the number of columns increases. Have I missed something obvious? I've done a TONNE of Googling but most posts for 'performance' and 'storage spaces' only seem to talk about parity.

**Disk speed test results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to me : You have one fast disk and three slow USB disks.

The more columns/disks that you use in addition to your fast disk,
meaning the more slow disks that are used, the over-all performance
is degrading as the number of used slow disks is increasing.

The read speed is improving, perhaps because for reading the disk driver
can issue read requests in parallel, but perhaps more because for more disks
it allocates more cache memory. The results of utilities like
CrystalDiskMark may be heavily influenced by the handling of the disk
by the operating system, so are to be taken with care.
These utilities tend too much to read the data that they wrote,
so testing the cache speed rather than the disk speed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've been doing some more experimenting, just with two disks in external USB docks. I'm having all sorts of problems. Disk pools not appearing, disk S/Ns changing in PowerShell Get-PhysicalDisk list. Not sure if I have a dodgy dock or what, but it's really hampering my investigations. 
I can't believe how hard it is to bunch together some old disks and get max performance from them!

Comment: "old disks" and "max performance" possibly may not go together.

Comment: I don't mean 'max performance' as in mind-blowing speed, I mean as in getting the best out of what I have.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar performance with ASM1166 chipset on a NVME port. Mirrored disks have performance of a single disk, which is expected. But 3 or 5 disks (parity) with aligned interleaving and cluster size behave similar to what you show.

This [person](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2SW47HKJ3SYH1/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewpnt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B09BMBPZLZ#R2SW47HKJ3SYH1) also has a similar issue. Wonder whether this is related to ASM1166 using 2 PCIe lanes. In your case, I would think that the 3 USB disk are also sharing 1 lane.